# Conditional default from ActionMailer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm trying to figure out the logic so when a user selects a dropdown selection, it uses that email address as the default `from`. For example, if the user selects `store1`, it should send from `test1@example.com`, `store2` should be `test2@example.com`, etc.

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "test1@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

This is the form the user uses to select a store:

```
<%= form_for @entry do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.select :store, Store.all.map { |store| [store.name]  }, :selected => @entry.store %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In the `stores` table, I have columns `name` and `email_address`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use `default` to do this - `default` is for the case when you *don't* want to customize the email.

When you write the delivery method, accept `entry` or `store` as an argument and use it to pick the `from` address at runtime. It would look something like

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'mailer'

  def entry_email(entry)
    mail(from: entry.store.email_address)
  end
end
```

And you would call it with

```
ApplicationMailer.entry_email(entry).deliver
```